# display message if there is no selected data on select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i use an `input type="checkbox"` inside `select tag` html and use this code to display all the selected data. but the problem i encounter is that when i unselect all the selected data the "SELECT" message doesn't show up..

and when i tried to use `var ret = $(".hida").show();` "SELECT" message show up if i unselect 1 data what i wanted to achieve is that "SELECT" message will only shows if i unselect all the data that i selected before.

```js
$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
        var ret = $(".hida");

        $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown"> 

                        <dt>
                            <a href="#">
                              <span class="hida">Select</span>    
                              <p class="multiSel"></p>  
                            </a>
                        </dt>

                        <dd>
                            <div class="mutliSelect">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Palliative/Hospice care" /> Palliative/Hospice care
                                    <li>
                                       <input type="checkbox" value="Prescription therapy" /> Prescription therapy
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Physical therapy" /> Physical therapy
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Rehabilitation" /> Rehabilitation
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Complex wound dressings" /> Complex wound dressings
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Tube feeding" /> Tube feeding
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="personal_grooming" name="personal_grooming"/> Personal grooming
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Meal preparations" /> Meal preparations
                                    <li>
                                         <input type="checkbox" value="Assistance in administering medication" /> Assistance in administering medication
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                         <input type="checkbox" value="Errands and transaportation" /> Errands and transaportation
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Companionship" /> Companionship
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="Medical Reminders" /> Medical Reminders
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: check the update.

Comment: give all checkboxes the same class name, then check for it: if ($('.chkClass').is(':checked')) {

Comment: Maybe you are searching for *Select2* functinality...

See https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox (or other configurations in the same page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count of all `checked` checkboxes and if equal to 0, then display `Select`. Hope this is what you are looking for?

```js
$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
 var title = $(this).val() + ",";
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
  $('.multiSel').append(html);
  $(".hida").hide();
 } else {
  $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
  //var ret = $(".hida");
  //$('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
  if ($('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length === 0)
   $(".hida").show();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown">
<dt>
 <a href="#">
  <span class="hida">Select</span>    
  <p class="multiSel"></p>  
 </a>
</dt>

<dd>
 <div class="mutliSelect">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Palliative/Hospice care" /> Palliative/Hospice care
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" value="Prescription therapy" /> Prescription therapy
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Physical therapy" /> Physical therapy
      <li>
       <input type="checkbox" value="Rehabilitation" /> Rehabilitation
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Complex wound dressings" /> Complex wound dressings
        <li>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Tube feeding" /> Tube feeding
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="personal_grooming" name="personal_grooming" />                                                Personal grooming
          <li>
           <input type="checkbox" value="Meal preparations" /> Meal preparations
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Assistance in administering medication" />                                                        Assistance in administering medication
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Errands and transaportation" /> Errands
            and transaportation
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Companionship" /> Companionship
           </li>
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Medical Reminders" /> Medical Reminders
           </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </dd>
</dl>
```